# Adding prefix to value in SQL row values

Tags: sql

I have about 10000 rows in SQL table, and I need to add a prefix before each value of user column.

Example: I have value names like John, Smith, and so on, and I need to set QA-John, QA-Smith, and so on.

Is there an SQL function that can do it automatically or only can be done it one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
UPDATE my table SET column_name = CONCAT('prefix', column_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I haven't misunderstood, this is what You're asking..

```
Update Table set name="QA-"+name
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks but does not work changes all names (column name) to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table_name
set 
product = 'QA-'||column_name
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks but does not work changes all names (column name) to 0

Comment: @jose Silva it should work,please let me know which database you are using?

Comment: My database is set in phpMyadmin from wamp. Table name is profiles and column name is seller, where I have all the namesthat I need to add the prfix QA- before each value. I tried your sugestion but changes all the values to 0